# Strange trouble with a loop in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've just started studying programming at school. I've been having a problem getting my code to reject a non-numeric cin from the user. I figured out a way to do it but now this weird thing is happening when I put a number in I have to insert valid input 3 times before it will clear through the loop and go on to the next part of the program.

// Amount to be converted

```
if (exchangeRate == JAPANESE_EXCHANGE_RATE)
{
    cout << "How many " << currencyName << " do you need a conversion for?" << '\n' << '\n';
}
else
{
    cout << "How many " << currencyName << "s do you need a conversion for?" << '\n' << '\n';
}
do
{
    cin >> conversionAmount;
    cout << '\n' << '\n';
    if (conversionAmount > -1)
    {
        cout << '\n'; // nothing needs to be done, the number will be accepted and proccessed;
    }
    else if (!(cin >> conversionAmount) || conversionAmount < 0)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000000000000, '\n');
        cout << "That value does not work; try again";
        cout << '\n' << '\n';
    }
}
while (!(cin >> conversionAmount));
```

This is just the part of the code that is messing up; it runs perfectly except for the strange way I have to get it out of the loop. If you need any more of the code Ill happily post it. I just started studying programming so if you could also explain the logic behind my mistake it would help me greatly.

Comment: Related: You're reading with `cin >> conversionAmount` *four times*.  You should only need to do it *once*.

Comment: Don't be mean to your users; they don't like that!

Comment: Btw, changing your original posted text to address anything besides typos, and in-so-doing utterly invalidating anyone's posted comments or answers, isn't helpful. If you want to demonstrate a change *you* made to your question code, post it in the question as an *addendum*, usually noted with a bold **Edit:** or update markup.

Comment: Sorry I realized the way I had my code written made my intent unclear. This is my first day as a member so I will learn the rules; I apologize to whozcraig. What I changed was that in the if statement I had if((cin >> conversionAmount)) because I thought it would do the opposite of the if else statement which if im correct checks that the input is in the format I initialized my variable named conversionAmount which is in this case double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you execute `cin >> conversionAmount` your input stream (cin) is waiting for an input. If you look at your code you have 4 `cin >> conversionAmount` in your loop. So you need to enter your input 4 times to go to the next iteration.

However, overall it is preferred to use stringstreams rather than reading directly from cin. look at this [Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

> As you can see, extracting from cin seems to make the task of getting input from the standard input pretty simple and straightforward. But this method also has a big drawback. What happens in the example above if the user enters something else that cannot be interpreted as an integer? Well, in this case, the extraction operation fails. And this, by default, lets the program continue without setting a value for variable i, producing undetermined results if the value of i is used later.
>
> This is very poor program behavior. Most programs are expected to behave in an expected manner no matter what the user types, handling invalid values appropriately. Only very simple programs should rely on values extracted directly from cin without further checking. A little later we will see how stringstreams can be used to have better control over user input.

Comment: Alright thank you, I think I understand what is going on. So you kind of understand the purpose of this part of my program. I am converting the amount given here between US dollars and another specified currency from a set list of possibilities. I am needing to get a real number and im trying to loop and prompt for a new input if a non numeric or negative numeric value is input. How would you write this in my program?

Comment: 'getline (cin,mystr);
stringstream(mystr) >> conversionAmount;                                                 if (stringstream.fail()) {..} else {...}' I hope this makes sense for you.

Comment: Yea that seems to be what Im trying to accomplish with the !(cin) part. What is the purpose of the stringstream(mystr) >> conversionAmount? Is that to put the string input in the conversionAmount variable memory space? Can I not just say getline (cin,conversionAmount)?

Comment: The point is you read everything from input as string then you use stringstream to see if it is a valid input or not. This way, you write `cin << var` once and get the result that you wanted.

Comment: When I try to use stringstream it gives me a syntax error and says that 'incomplete type is not allowed'. How should I go about correcting this?

Comment: '#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string myStr;
  getline(cin, myStr);
  stringstream myStream(myStr);
  int var;
  myStream >> var;
  if (myStream.fail())
    cout << "Failed";
  else
    cout << "Passed";
  return 0;

}
'